# pyquery (lxml) not finding a tag in a well-structured XML document?

Tags: python, lxml, pyquery

I have an XML file that looks like [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00636649?displayxml=true). The relevant bit is this:

```
<reference>
  <citation>Vander Wal JS, Gang CH, Griffing GT, Gadde KM. Escitalopram for treatment of night eating syndrome: a 12-week, randomized, placebo-controlled trial. J Clin Psychopharmacol. 2012 Jun;32(3):341-5. doi: 10.1097/JCP.0b013e318254239b.</citation>
  <PMID>22544016</PMID>
</reference>
```

I am trying to find the value of the `PMID` field, using PyQuery to parse the XML:

```
    from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

    text = open(f, 'r').read()
    d = pq(text)
    data = {}       
    data['nct_id'] = d('nct_id').text()

    print d('reference')
    reference = d('reference')
    print reference('PMID')
    data['pmid'] = reference('PMID').text()

    print data['PMID']
```

Why isn't this working? In the console I see the full content of `reference` from the first print statement, followed by two empty values:

```
<reference>
    <citation>Vander Wal JS, Gang CH, Griffing GT, Gadde KM. Escitalopram for treatment of night eating syndrome: a 12-week, randomized, placebo-controlled trial. J Clin Psychopharmacol. 2012 Jun;32(3):341-5. doi: 10.1097/JCP.0b013e318254239b.</citation>
    <PMID>22544016</PMID>
  </reference>
```

I can find other leaf nodes in the document (like `nct_id`) just fine using `.find()`, as the example code shows.

Is it that PyQuery doesn't like upper-case tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specifiy the parser to use and it will work:

```
d = pq(text, parser='xml')
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!